# Joomla Clean Cache - Delete Failed

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Joomla 1.5: I enabled SSL on a particular menu item. The menu item failed to switch to https, which prompted me to google a solution. One forum said the problem was resolved by clearing the cache. So, I went to tools/clean cache, selected all under "site" and hit the delete button. This resulted in a swag of errors - one for each item I tried to delete, saying `"Delete failed: 'index.html'"`

Anybody know what's the happs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to 'Help' -> 'System info' -> 'Directory permissions' in the /administrator/ area of your website you should get a list of folders with info on whether they are writeable or not.

I suspect your /cache/ folder is unwriteable - so you will need to change permissions on the folder in question to allow Joomla/PHP/Apache to delete the files from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if cache folder is defined corectly. You can change cache folder location in "Site > Global configuration"

Answer (score 0):

Excecute the following command on your webroot

Code:

```
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 administrator/backups/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 administrator/components/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 administrator/language/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 administrator/language/en-GB
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 administrator/modules/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 administrator/templates/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 components/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 images/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 images/banners/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 images/stories/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 language/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 language/en-GB
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 language/pdf_fonts/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 media/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 modules/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 plugins/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 plugins/content/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 plugins/editors
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 plugins/editors-xtd/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 plugins/search/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 plugins/system/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 plugins/user/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 plugins/xmlrpc/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 templates/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 cache/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 administrator/cache/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 logs/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 tmp/
-bash-3.1$ chmod 777 configuration.php
-bash-3.1$ chmod -R 777 cache/
-bash-3.1$ chmod -R 777 administrator/cache/
```

Then go to TOOLS -> CLEAN CACHE on the administrator site and select all and delete.

The above steps fixed my issue.